# Meaning of 持てない in 充電中は持てないほど暑くなるんだけど

Tags: meaning

Someone was talking about the properties of a charger
But i don't understand the meaning of 持てない in:

> 充電中は持てないほど暑くなるんだけど

Comment: 熱く ＞ 暑く, definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the "potential form" ([可能形]{か・のう・けい}) of 持つ.  I means "can't hold".  So your sentence means

> While charging, it will become hot enough that you can't hold it.