# usage of でないほど in this sentence

Tags: grammar

これは教科書に書いてある文です。

> 明治時代に入ると、徐々に洋服化が進み、一般にも普及した。 **現在では、男性も女性も世界の一流デザイナーのプレタポルテを身に着けることが特別でないほど、すっかり洋服が定着している。** その需要の高さから、ファッションショーの舞台もパリ、ニューヨークから東京へ移りつつあると言われるほどである。
>
> ...
>
> 現在では、男性も女性も世界の一流デザイナーのプレタポルテを身に着けることが特別**でないほど**、すっかり洋服が定着している。

しかし、その「でないほど」の意味がわかりません。

Googleを利用して「でないほど」を検索したら、結果がたくさん出て来たけど、大半の結果は動詞「でる」の否定形「でない」に関係するので、この質問の「名詞+でないほど、・・・」に説明できません。

StackExchangeにも「でないほど」に関する質問がありますけど、

[Meaning of 持てない in 充電中は持てないほど暑くなるんだけど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24073/meaning-of-%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-in-%E5%85%85%E9%9B%BB%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AF%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9%E6%9A%91%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9)

これは「動詞てないほど」の結果で、Googleの結果と同じのようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 現在では、男性も女性も世界の一流デザイナーのプレタポルテを身に着けることが特別**でないほど**、すっかり洋服が定着している。

この文における「特別で**ない**」は、「特別で**ある**」の否定形です。従って、動詞「出る」とは無関係の表現になります。

文自体の主節は「すっかり洋服が定着している」です。文の前半ではありません。

では、**どの程度**日本に「すっかり洋服が定着している」かを説明するためのひとつの具体例として、「男性も女性も世界の一流デザイナーのプレタポルテを身に着けることが特別でない」という事実をあげているのです。（「ほど」は「程度」の同類語です。）

要するに、「A ほど B」という文型は、A という事例をあげることによって、B という状態の程度を表しているのです。ご理解いただけたでしょうか。

例文：

「東京の新大久保では、ここは本当に日本かと疑っても不思議では**ないほど**、韓国系の住民が増えている。」

Comment: "で**は**ないほど"の"は"を省略してもいいですか

Comment: つまり"でないほど"の原形は"ではないほど"ですか

Comment: @himmelblau 「ではない」の「は」は、必ず付けなければいけないものではありません https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19662/7810